# Standardized opentelemetry log format

Tags: logging, open-telemetry

Is there something like standardized [opentelemetry](https://opentelemetry.io/) log format?
If the answer is yes where can I find example of that? :)

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there isn't any *standardized* opentelemetry log format. However, there is a data model defined by the logs SDK here https://github.com/open-telemetry/oteps/blob/main/text/logs/0097-log-data-model.md. One of the goals is to make it work with the existing logging ecosystem, transform and transport the logs along with other signals. You can find the number of examples there.

Comment: > One of the goals is to make it work with the existing logging ecosystem, **transform** and transport the logs along with other signals.

This "transform" word I am particularly interested. Transform it to what exactly?

Comment: Log data model I lined to

Comment: https://github.com/open-telemetry/oteps/blob/main/text/logs/0097-log-data-model.md#log-and-event-record-definition

Comment: Is there any example how this transformation should be done in programming language (preferably Go) because right now I can't understand if I should do if manually or maybe there is an API for it.

Comment: There will be SDK(which is not implemented yet) that does this.

Comment: Will be SDK for automatic transformation from "standard" logs to this opentelemetry log format or will be SDK for creating this LOG objects described here -> https://github.com/open-telemetry/oteps/blob/main/text/logs/0097-log-data-model.md ?, because at the moment such things are not clear to me. :)

Comment: Your questions is not clear to me. What is `"standard" logs`? What does this mean _SDK for creating this LOG objects_? SDK will (automatically) transform the logs emitted by your application and transport them to OTLP collector.

Comment: https://github.com/open-telemetry/oteps/blob/main/text/logs/0097-log-data-model.md#appendix-a-example-mappings let's say those are "standard" logs, that is logs generated by RFC5424 Syslog, Windows Event Log, SignalFx Events, Log4j etc.
> "What does this mean SDK for creating this LOG objects?"
https://github.com/open-telemetry/oteps/blob/main/text/logs/0097-log-data-model.md#log-and-event-record-definition
How can I create log object in golang that represent this data structure?

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, SDK is not implemented yet. Even if it were implemented, you probably wouldn't be able to use them directly or would be advised against that since this is not intended as specified in NOTE here https://github.com/open-telemetry/oteps/blob/main/text/logs/0150-logging-library-sdk.md#specification

Comment: So basically the only thing this opentelemetry project have when it comes to logs is this "concept" (the list of fields in a log record) and that's it?

Comment: No, there is an early version of SDK work going/completed in some languages but not go. Most of projects have been working on tracing until now and going forward it will be metrics. You can safely assume that It will be few months when logs becomes the active development.